# MyAppDomain AssemblyResolve C#

Tags: c#, appdomain, assembly-loading

I have a DLL which i use in an Environment where i need to handle the Load of external assemblys myself. I want to load an assembly into an AppDomain. This works fine when i try this with the CurrentAppDomain, but i fail when doing this into a appdomain which i create myself.
The background is that i want to unload the appdomain at the end so that the assembly is "released" in the end.

```
public ZipEx() 
{
    try
    {
        AppDomainSetup domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup();
        domaininfo.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        Evidence adevidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;

        //THIS CODE WORKS
        //System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
        //System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib");

        //THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK
        AppDomain zipDomain2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ADZib2", adevidence, domaininfo);
        PolicyLevel polLevel = PolicyLevel.CreateAppDomainLevel();
        PermissionSet permSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
        permSet.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.AllFlags));
        polLevel.RootCodeGroup.PolicyStatement = new PolicyStatement(permSet);
        zipDomain2.SetAppDomainPolicy(polLevel);
        zipDomain2.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ex in ctor" + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString());
    }
    if (_loadedAssembly == null)
    {
    }
}

Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve");
    Assembly assembly = null;
    bool foundAssembly = false;

    int idx = args.Name.IndexOf(',');
    if (idx > 0)
    {
        string partialName = args.Name.Substring(0, idx);
        string dllName = partialName + ".dll";

        //Add the directorys where the assembly hould be resolved
        List<string> directorySearch = new List<string>
        {
          string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",Environment.CurrentDirectory,Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, dllName),
          string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",AppPath,Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, dllName)
        };

        foreach (string fileName in directorySearch)
        {
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                foundAssembly = true;
                assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (assembly == null)
        {
            if (!foundAssembly)
            {
                foreach (string fileName in directorySearch)
                {
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }
    if (assembly != null) 
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("assembly is not null");
    }
    return assembly;
}
```

My question is how do i use an appdomain which i created to load an assembly ?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean?  No event, an exception, etc.?

Comment: Hard to see why you are not using the zipDomain2.AssemblyResolve event.  Or not just setting up the AppDomainSetup the way you like it.  Use Fuslogvw.exe for troubleshooting.

Comment: @Steve Mitcham i mean it raises an exeption that the assembly is not found. My problem is that it works with the CurrentDomain

Comment: As @HansPassant said, the fuslogvw.exe will give you the paths that the CLR is using to try and resolve your assemblies so you'll be able to figure out why it isn't finding the files.

Comment: Okay i will try that, but why does the same Resolve method work with the CurrentDomain ?

Answer (score 1):

In your current example, I don't see any uncommented code that would cause the newly created AppDomain to try and load an assembly. I'm assuming in this answer that there's a call to Load that's missing from your uncommented code.

According to the remarks in the help for [AppDomain.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36az8x58(v=vs.110).aspx), it should only be used in the current AppDomain because otherwise it will try to load the assembly into BOTH AppDomains, which is likely why you're getting an exception. To load an assembly into only the other AppDomain, you should call one of the CreateInstance functions. In this particular case, I'd recommend the [CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h7t2a2(v=vs.110).aspx) function since it will allow you to specify an assembly by name as well as a type.

If you don't have a type you want to instantiate and be able to interact with across AppDomain boundaries (which seems unlikely but possible), you may have to create and discard some simple type like an enum or struct to get this to work.

Comment: This isn't terribly relevant to you since your code makes it clear that you're loading a DLL, but for others that stop by this question, one can also use [AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxx9f4c2(v=vs.110).aspx) to run an executable in another AppDomain without explicitly creating any of its types.

Comment: I Will give the whole thing a try. Thanks for the hint, i will see what i can accomplish with it

Comment: Darn, I just realized something else. If the code you have above is the code you're using and it's failing even without the call to Load, you may also be getting this exception when you hook up the AssemblyResolve event because the new AppDomain then tries to load the original DLL or EXE (the one with your CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve method in it) and can't because it's not in the ApplicationBase path for the new AppDomain. If that's the case, you could try putting a copy of the original executable in the directory you're trying to load from and see if that helps at all.

Comment: I can't copy it because inno setup copies all assemblies into a temp directory, but not all in the same